How to mimic a real if statement with dsl.IfPresentPlaceholder using kfp v2?
I am migrating some legacy code using Kubeflow pipeline v1 (kfp 1.8.22) that was using python code to generate component.yaml. Now when migrating to Kubeflow pipeline v2 (kfp 2.7.0), I am using dsl.ContainerSpec. I managed to implement something that is working but I struggle with passing boolean argument for which dsl.IfPresentPlaceholder doesn't seems to offer a robust solution.
@dsl.container_component
def create_test_training_component(
    dry_run: bool = None,

):


    args = [dsl.IfPresentPlaceholder(input_name='dry_run', then=['--dry-run'])]

    return dsl.ContainerSpec(image=image,
                             command=[
                                 "python",
                                 "-m",
                                 "task.trainer_task"
                             ],
                             args=args
                             )

Now when I call this component in my pipeline:
    dry_run_training_cpu_task = create_test_training_component(
        dry_run=True,
    ).set_display_name("Dry run on CPU for training")

The issue is that any argument "True" or "False" will results in having the option '--dry-run'.
Is there a way to mimic standard and robust IF statement using dsl.IfPresentPlaceholder? I cannot python logic in create_test_training_component.
Is there another way to create container_component to achieve what I want ?
